# Using the 6800M dGPU of my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, laptop, asus, radeon

So I have the Asus Strix G513QY with a Ryzen 9 5900HX and a Radeon 6800M 12GB as dGPU.

Now I set up Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 in dual boot alongside Windows 10.
By default, the system doen't recognize my dGPU which is unfortunate because I need it for the DP output and obviously for some more demanding tasks.

I then decided to install the drivers from AMD's website [1](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-30) using the install command.
That didn't work either, I assume because they are probably only made for the desktop 6000 series.

So now my question: Is there still some way to get that card running in Ubuntu or do I have to wait till proper drivers are released (if they are being made)?

Answer (score 0):

Try update kernel to 5.13 or 5.14 from mainline rep.

Rgds

Comment: I did and it works temporary. However the Driver is really buggy. It keeps crashing after like half an hour and then there is just a single frame with a lot of artifacts. Other times it doesn't work at all after booting.